# Data Dictionary of website without database

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, validation, waterfall

I am trying to understand if an e-commerce website without database, built with node.js would still have the capability to produce a passive Data Dictionary?? Is a database mandatory to produce a data dictionary?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to have a database in order to build an e-commerce website. Because the data dictionary may just include a summary (column names, types, etc.) of the tables in the database. Actually it is just a repository of information about data in a database or a data set.